# Linq Comparar duas listas de tipos diferentes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Tenho duas listas diferentes A `List<ProdutoTag>` e B = `List<Tag>`:

```
public class ProdutoTag
{
    public Int64 ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public Int32 TagId { get; set; }
    public Double Peso { get; set; }
    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
    public virtual Produto Produto { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public Int32 TagId { get; set; }
    public String Descricao { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProdutoTag> ProdutosTags { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Resposta> Respostas { get; set; }        
}
```

Preciso verificar se a lista A contém todos os elementos da lista B *(Se a lista A possuir outros elementos que a lista B não possui, tubo bem, mas a lista A deve ter todos os elementos da lista B)*.

A forma de de comparar as duas listas é através da property A.

Seria algo parecido com (onde x.ProdutosTags é minha lista A):

```
// Busco na base de dados todos os produtos
var produtos = _context.Produtos.ToList();
// Agora preciso apenas dos produtos que contenham todas as tags selecionadas
var selecionados = produtos.Where(x => x.ProdutosTags.Contains(B));
```

***Como posso comparar duas listas de tipos diferentes?***

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assim:

```
var aContemB = !b.Except(a.Select(p => p.Tag).ToList()).Any();
```

Ou seja, verifica se algum item de B é exceção em relação a A, e verifica se o resultado possui elementos.

Se houver algum erro, procure materializar as duas listas antes da comparação, ou seja:

```
var listaA = a.Select(p => p.Tag).ToList();
var listaB = b.ToList(); // Isto garante que todos os SQL foram executados antes da comparação.
var aContemB = !listaB.Except(listaA).Any();
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Usei `var aContemB = !tags.Except(produtos.Select(p => p.ProdutosTags.Select(x => x.Tag)).ToList());` e estou recebendo o erro: Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Domain.Entities.Tag>' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Domain.Entities.Tag>>' O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Acho que você terá que executar os comandos em separado. Vou melhorar o exemplo.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda, mas ainda não deu certo. Tenho uma lista de produtos. Cada produto desta lista possui uma lista de Tags (TagProduto). Preciso obter apenas os produtos cujas tags sejam as mesmas da minha lista B (onde B lista de tags)

Comment: Isto eu acho que já seria outra pergunta, que extrapola o escopo desta pergunta. Gostaria de abrir outra pergunta?